# Xsl stylesheet empty result Datapower

Tags: web-services, ibm-datapower

Good Morning.

I need some help with that:

I have a XML  firewall with loopback backend. Either I have a web services that can login in my local machine with a code, and the response show my in the same lable: "code", a new code.

The problem is, when i build the XML firewall, in the policy rules, I use the tranform with XSL, but the response service is empty.

The code of my xsl is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" extension-element-prefixes="dp" xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions">
    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="call_IdentToken">
        <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.ws.identify.com" xmlns:code="http://code.ws.identify.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:validaCode>
         <ser:obj>
            <code:code>2016</code:code>

         </ser:obj>
      </ser:validaCode>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
    </xsl:variable>     

    <xsl:variable name="result_IdentToken" select="dp:soap-call('http://localhost:8080/ValidaCodigo/services/ImplCode', $call_IdentToken)"/>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: you probably want the `regex` namespace prefix also in the declared `extension-element-prefixes`. Also your input might have a namespace that would at least have to be declared

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet does not output anything.  If you want it to return the contents of the `result_IdentToken` variable, you should copy it to the output context after you set it.

```
<xsl:copy-of select="$result_IdentToken"/>
```